# Windows 8: window is black or white after maximizing

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, memory, cpu

Window of any program is black or white after maximizing it and the computer is very slow until the actuall view of program is drawn (it takes at least 5 seconds).
This occurs after working for a long time in some RAM consuming software or after resuming Windows from sleep.
This is how it looks like:
[image: This is how it looks like]

My system:
Intel core i3-3120M  2.50 GHz
RAM 4 GB

Previously I had a computer with i5 and 4GB RAM and these things almost never occured.
So is it a RAM problem or I need a more powerful processor ?

Comment: Is your HDD reporting itself as Healthy?

Comment: What do you mean with "Healthy" ?

Comment: update the GPU driver and look if it fixes the issue.

Comment: have you tried the new GPU driver which was released a few days ago? https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&keyword=HD%20Graphics%204000

Comment: Yes. I think it's Windows 8 in general. Previously I used Windows 7 and it was very fast.

Answer (score 0):

We have seen such issue occuring when minimize or maximize google chrome. By disabling "Use hardware acceleration when available" option in Settings > Advanced Settings > System, resolved the issue. Please give a try and check the outcome.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my case this happens with every program, even Windows explorer's folders

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. Every time my laptop is slow I look at the task manager and there is 5% CPU usage, 60% RAM and 100% Disk. I think the problem is my 500GB @ 5400 RPM hard drive.
I will try to change it with somethinkg faster.

This is the article that pointed that out: http://thebestlaptops.net/upgrade-your-5400rpm-hard-drive-laptop/